# search for data in the subform and have it return the correct firm record in the main form

Tags: ms-access

Novice alert! 
I made a simple database to manage international business contacts. It was supposed to be for personal use but now my boss suddenly wants to present it to the company board tomorrow! One table, "Firms", contains the firm's capabilities, etc. The other table, "contacts" contains our contacts at the firms with their addresses and contact info. The relationship is one-to-many between the tables.  The main form uses fields from the firm table and has a subform for contact info entry. Most of the time I know that the form will be searched using the firm data in the main form. However, I know that an even more novice person than me will eventually want to search for a contact's name in the subform and have it return the correct firm record in the main form. How do I do this? Filter by form seems to only work on the main form. I couldn't find anything that worked in the forums.

Comment: The file provided in [this thread](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=99353) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a form Find Contact, this can be a pop-up from your form. There is no point in searching the subform, because you will not find all contacts that way. Once the contact is found, get the firm ID and find the firm in the main form.

You can use a list box for the contacts and find the firm on the main form either when the contact is selected or by a button on the pop-up, this will allow your users to look through a selection of contacts without having to close the form.